# What's the difference between [attribute~=value] and [attribute*=value]?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What's the difference between these two jQuery selectors?

Here are the definitions from w3schools.com:

- The `[attribute~=value]` selector selects each element with a
  specific attribute, with a value containing a specific string.
- The `[attribute*=value]` selector selects each element with a
  specific attribute, with a value containing a string.

**UPDATE:**

Here are the definitions from jquery.com. This answers my question:

- `[attribute~=value]` - Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.
- `[attribute*=value]` - Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

Comment: Always better to go to the source:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/ 
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Tip: Don't use w3schools.com. Directly read the documentation of the library or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*=` is **attributeContains selector** , From [**jquery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

> > Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

`~=` is **attributeContainsWord selector** , From [**jquery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/):

> > Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

See [**attributeContains selector with Example of usage here**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) and [**attributeContainsWord selector with example and usage here**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

The **attributeContains selector** is for the string to be contained in the attribute value while **attributeContainsWord selector** is for string seperated with delimeted space. The official jquery examples clearly explain it.

### EXPLANATION:

### Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]

**HTML:**

```
<input name="man-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letterman2">
<input name="newmilk">
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$( "input[name*='man']" ).val( "has man in it!" );
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**DEMO EXAMPLE:**

[Example of Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://jsfiddle.net/wks0xjzk/)

### Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~="value"]

**HTML:**

```
<input name="man-news">
<input name="milk man">
<input name="letterman2">
<input name="newmilk">
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$( "input[name~='man']" ).val( "mr. man is in it!" );
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**DEMO EXAMPLE:**

[Example of Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~="value"]](http://jsfiddle.net/rfw8h705/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Those are not jQuery selectors, they're CSS attribute-selectors.

> `~=` - Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.
>
> `*=` - Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

The *difference* is that, given the following HTML:

```
<span class="abcd efg">First</span>
<span class="abcdefg">Second</span>
```

`[class*=abcd]` will match both elements (since it searches the listed attribute for *any* occurrence of the given string), whereas `[class~=abcd]` will match only the first (because it looks for a white-space separated occurrence of the given string).

```css
[class*=abcd] {
  color: #f00;
}

[class~=abcd] {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<span class="abcd efg">First</span>
<span class="abcdefg">Second</span>
```

References:

- [CSS Attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Comment: No, they are actually jQuery selectors too.

Comment: In the sense that jQuery allows them to be used. By passing them to the browser's native `document.querySelectorAll()`, where available, otherwise parsing it via Sizzle. They are *allowed* in jQuery, but they remain CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("[class*='b']").css("color", "green");
$("[class~='b']").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="a b c">1st</p>
<p class="abc">2nd</p>
<p class="a b c">3rd</p>
<p class="abc">4th</p>
<p class="adc">5th</p>
```

.

`*=` means the attribute contains the value x (as a substring).
`~=` means the attribute contains a list of words separated by spaces and x is one of them.
read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [attribute*=value] ,  a[href*="test"]
> ```
>
> Selects every  element whose href attribute value contains the
>   substring "test"

---

> [attribute~=value] ,  [title~=flower]
>
> Selects all elements with a
>   title attribute containing the word "flower"

Answer (score 0):

The difference is, that the "contains" operator (`*= value`) look for these characters **anywhere** in the attribute, whereas "contains word" (`~= value`) looks only for whole **words**.

**I would recommend you to rather avoid looking at w3schools definitions, and use official library API (like [this for the contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) and [this for contains word selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)). For other matters, I'd recommend [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org) or the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) specification directly.**